# How to fire a Trigger when a variable surpasses/exceed a specific Date

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with an atributte of type "DATE" and I want to fire a Trigger when the atributte achieve a specific date.

For example:

```
Table A:
        a int primary key;
        d Date;

A(1, '15-05-2015');
```

When this date arrives I want to fire a specific trigger.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you want a scheduled job to run each day, doing whatever work needs to be done on the matching rows.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I'm doing a "Light" DB project and I think that it would be too advanced. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

According to Oracle's [trigger documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm):

> You can write triggers that fire whenever one of the following
>   operations occurs:
>
> 1. DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) on
>      a particular table or view, issued by any user
> 2. DDL
>      statements (CREATE or ALTER primarily) issued either by a particular
>      schema/user or by any schema/user in the database
> 3. Database
>      events, such as logon/logoff, errors, or startup/shutdown, also issued
>      either by a particular schema/user or by any schema/user in the
>      database

**The arrival of a date is not one of these unfortunately.**

You could, however create an Oracle job that would run at a specific date and execute an Oracle procedure

Oracle's [job creation documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm#ADMIN12384) illustrates how to do it:

```
BEGIN DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (    job_name           => 
'update_sales',    job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',   
job_action         =>  'OPS.SALES_PKG.UPDATE_SALES_SUMMARY',   
start_date         =>  '28-APR-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',   
repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2', /* every other day */ 
end_date           =>  '20-NOV-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',   
job_class          =>  'batch_update_jobs',    
comments           =>  'My new job'); 
END; 
/
```

The "**job_action**" field receive the name of the procedure to be executed and "**repeat_interval**" is to be left blank for a one-of execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a before insert/update for each row trigger, which fires every time you insert/update on this table. In trigger body you can test

```
if :new.d = to_date('2015-05-15','yyyy-mm-dd') then
  --put you code here
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER trg_ex
   AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON ex1
      FOR EACH ROW
      WHEN ( NEW.DATE='--'  )
   BEGIN
       dbms_output.Put_line('Trigger is fired');
   END;
/
```

Comment: We want the trigger to be fired when that specific date arrives, not by updating, deleting or inserting a row. Basically, some trigger exists that do the update, insert or delete in some other table, but that trigger is fired when the specific date is achived.

Comment: @Silva_PT_SCP logicaly speaking , when a date changed from value to value , isnt considered updating ? when that date change its values , it means its updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER yourtable_before_insupd
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON yourtable
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (NEW.date = '15-05-2015')

DECLARE
   -- your declarations here - v_date is just an example
   v_date DATE;

BEGIN
   -- your computations here
   -- Find date of the item - just as example
   SELECT date INTO v_date
   FROM dual;


   -- update the date of the item - just as example
   :new.date := sysdate;

END;
```